# Does my app get uploaded to expo when creating a build?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I just created a build with expo. I monitored the building process closely. Since it was not a final release build I selected the option that expo handles the `keystore`. After that I saw a couple of messages that made me think if my code got uploaded to Expo.

This is the console stack trace:

```
[07:10:44] Publishing to channel 'default'...    //What does the publishing mean? Is this going to be publicly available?
[07:10:46] Building iOS bundle
[07:11:28] Building Android bundle
[07:12:18] Analyzing assets
[07:12:22] Uploading assets
[07:12:24] Uploading /assets/refund-title.png
[07:12:24] Uploading /assets/drawer-cover3.jpg
[07:12:25] Processing asset bundle patterns:
[07:12:25] - /Users/bbh/Coding/React Native Apps/refundtracker_expo/**/*
[07:12:25] Uploading JavaScript bundles         //My code gets uploaded to expo, why?
[07:12:41] Published
```

On the expo website I followed the building process and saw at the end the following:

```
...
uploading build artifact to S3
...
```

I just wanted to ask if my code is now publicly available or if the code just got uploaded to the expo servers for processing the build and ultimately uploaded to S3 to make the build available for me on their website. Or did my code got uploaded and is now somehow available to other people? Maybe somebody from expo can answer.

Answer (score 1):

This from there official document **[Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/introduction/faq/)**

> The default privacy setting for Expo apps is unlisted so nobody can
>   find your app unless you share the link with them.

And the code is not publicly available. So, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: After around 4 years of this post, when I am trying to use reactnative with expo, I have the same question as in this post. You mentioned that code is not publicly available, but the source code gets uploaded to the cloud?

Comment: ...probably... it's like github saying "trust us"... and then copilot comes along recommending competitors code chunks. why wouldn't they upload your code to themselves? huge value for them in the long run game. also pure gold for the business intelligence industry.